# Equation for Terminal Velocity on an inclined plane and the time it takes to reach it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, drag

Now I'm doing a research on the matter similar to this thread : [Terminal Velocity of identical shape/size objects](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75942/terminal-velocity-of-two-equally-shaped-sized-objects-with-different-weights)

which is very self explanatory and very helpful. However in my case, the objects will be sliding down an **inclined plane** instead of falling perpendicularly to the ground. In that case, would the equation for the terminal velocity be
$$
v_{t} = \sqrt{\frac{2mg\sin{\theta}}{{\rho}AC_{d}}}  ?
$$
Then I'd have to differentiate 
$$
\dot{v}(t) = g\sin{\theta}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{{\rho}AC_{d}}{m}v(t)^2
$$ 
to find the time it takes to reach the terminal velocity?

Comment: The component of force of gravity along the plane is the thing that matters. Depending on your definition of $\theta$, it does appear you are on the right track. But of course you never "reach" terminal velocity - you only ever get close to it. So rather than differentiating, you would look for the time "when the acceleration gets close to zero", where you get to define what 'close' means. Because these equations are asymptotic, acceleration will never be zero (unless the slope, that is $\theta$, becomes smaller over time).

Answer (score 1):

Direct integration give you the time it takes to go between $v_1$ and $v_2$.

$$ t = \int \limits_{v_1}^{v_2} \frac{1}{ \dot{v}(t)} \, {\rm d}v $$

So if $\dot{v}(t) = a_0 - \beta v^2$ then

$$ t = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{a_0 \beta}} \ln \left( \frac{a_0+\sqrt{a_0 \beta}(v_2-v_1)-\beta v_1 v_2 }{a_0-\sqrt{a_0 \beta}(v_2-v_1)-\beta v_1 v_2} \right) $$