# Entry equation for objects with different characteristics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, aerodynamics, matter

The question, which weighs more, one pound of feathers or one pound of black hole, comes to mind. Each would react wildly different reentering Earth's atmosphere. In order to narrow the question: **Is there a simple object/devise with the right parameters with the right entry angle that can enter the atmosphere to decelerate slowly without the need for heat shielding?** Like a feather or a partially filled balloon. May be a thin carbon fiber horizontal propeller drawing below. So when it begins to enter the atmosphere it spins it keeps the leading edge rotated. I tried to find a picture of such a tumbling rotor/propeller. [image] Feel free to edit!

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75942/terminal-velocity-of-two-equally-shaped-sized-objects-with-different-masses?rq=1